# Problem building project in IntelliJ 2020.1

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to build my project but I can't.

I get this error:
Error:Cannot run program "C:\tools\jdk8.0.191\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\"my user"\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\compile-server"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\"

Do anyone know what to do about this? Iøm trying to build in IntelliJ 2020.1

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be related to more strict command-line processing in JDK on Windows after JDK-8221858 (private) security patch see [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230268#focus=streamItem-27-4134350.0-0) for details.

Try following workaround: Help -> `Edit Custom VM Options` action and add the following line at the bottom of the file: `-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true` and restart IDE.